# MySQL SELECT COUNT GROUP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have table "orders" with column ID (id order) and IDU (id user).
I want calculate like this:

```
50 person have 1 order
30 person have 2 order
etc...
```

My code (bad)

```
SELECT DISTNICT count(id), count(idu)  FROM orders GROUP BY idu
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Could you please share your table structure along with some sample data?

Comment: do you want text like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call this a histogram of histogram queries.  You want to know how many users have a given order count.  The solution is to use subqueries and `group by` twice:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(idu), max(idu)
from (select idu, count(*) as cnt
      from orders
      group by idu
     ) ou
group by cnt;
```

When running this type of query, I usually include the min and max of the user id, so I can readily find examples of users (typically those that have many orders).

Comment: you mean `group by` twice ?

Comment: Loved that term **histogram of histogram**